# What's the difference between "な感じ" and "という感じ" when written after quotation marks?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

`な感じ` was crossed out and replaced with `という感じ` in a sentence that I wrote that was similar to this one:

> その文には「それは私にはもったいない」 <s>な感じ</s> **という感じ** があると思う。
>   I think that sentence has a feeling of "that's more than one deserves."

What's the difference between `な感じ` and `という感じ` when written after quotation marks?

Comment: ~な is the corresponding attributive　form (連体形) of the sentence ending (終止形) pattern [Noun/NounPhrase]だ. I think because you have these "「」" (which I do not know the names for), it has to be ~という since it's a quote.

Comment: Now I think this question is begging to be asked, "Doesn't wrapping text in quotations turn it into a noun phrase?". I have no confident answer, but I'm guessing "no".

Comment: @Flaw There are (at least) two usages for quotations marks. One is to cite fragments from another source and incorporate them into your sentence. In this use, quotation marks are syntactically invisible, and do not change the parts of speach of what is inside. In the second use, the quotation is used as complement/object of a verb like `言う`, `考える`, etc. In this usage, the quotation is similar to a noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`な` is the attributive ending of a na-adjective or a noun. The modifier to the noun `感じ` in your example ends with `ない`, which is an i-adjective, so it should not take `な`.

As Flaw comments, `「～ない」感じ` is generally possible, but that has two problems in this particular case. First, `私` will not work as intended. You can use `自分` instead. Second, since the description in the modifier is is made from a non first-person's perspective, it is more natural to insert `という`. You can go with either:

> その文には「自分にはもったいない」感じがあると思う。

Comment: Is it possible for nothing to be used between 「～ない」 and 感じ? (I.e. 「～ない」感じ) Since い-adjectives can directly modify a noun. Does the use of 「」 have other rules? Perhaps you could expand on this in your answer.

Comment: @Flaw I thought someone is going to ask that. It is a good question. Indeed, "「～ない」感じ" is possible. I will expand that.